# Same exact function syntax only works when copied from external code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a React tutorial. In the `Backdrop.js` file, there is a simple function that returns a `backdrop` and assigns an `onClick` `prop` to close an open `Modal` when one clicks the `backdrop`.

My code looks absolutely identical to me to the one in the tutorialist's Github repo. Somehow though, when I use my code for the function, the `Modal` doesn't close when I click the `backdrop`. However when I copy and paste his code directly from Github, the `Modal` does close when I click the `backdrop`.

I have no idea what's going on. As far as I can tell, there are no differences whatsoever between the two pieces of code.

**My code**:

```
function Backdrop(props) {
  return <div className='backdrop' onCLick={props.onClick} />;
}

export default Backdrop;
```

**His code**:

```
function Backdrop(props) {
  return <div className='backdrop' onClick={props.onClick} />;
}

export default Backdrop;
```

I'll even have both functions on the same page and if I comment mine out the app will work as intended, but if I comment his code out it doesn't work anymore. For ex, this works (my code on top commented out):

```
// function Backdrop(props) {
//   return <div className='backdrop' onCLick={props.onClick} />;
// }

// export default Backdrop;


function Backdrop(props) {
  return <div className='backdrop' onClick={props.onClick} />;
}

export default Backdrop;
```

But this doesn't:

```
function Backdrop(props) {
  return <div className='backdrop' onCLick={props.onClick} />;
}

export default Backdrop;


// function Backdrop(props) {
//   return <div className='backdrop' onClick={props.onClick} />;
// }

// export default Backdrop;
```

I do use the Prettier extension if that makes a difference. Could it mess the formatting somehow in an undetectable way?

Comment: Your onClick is spelled incorrectly, 'L' is capital. that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Backdrop(props) {
  return <div className='backdrop' onCLick={props.onClick} />;
}

export default Backdrop;
```

In your code is a capital L in "onClick". Change it to a lowercase l to make it work.

If you ever have a similar problem, you can use sites like [this](https://www.diffchecker.com/).

Comment: jesus christ...thank you! I've been staring at it for 15 minutes straight, I can't believe I didn't see that. I can't accept your answer for another 7 minutes, but I will

Comment: Thanks for the diffchecker, I was thinking of trying something like that

Comment: Even with the diffchecker it took me a minute. If I could help you, I'd appreciate if you could accept the answer.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: @Ruben, I just did, thanks for your help again. It wouldn't let me accept for a 10m or so after you answered